# Content relevant affiliate links - use nofollow?

Tags: affiliate

My site offers basically expert articles on various subjects.
Visitors often ask something like "OK, but what do you recommend i buy?"

So I decided to use an affiliate program. I make links to open an on-line shop's website and do a search with terms I defined when making the link, so it gives most useful products. Hence, link not "poiting" to a particular sale, but giving list of one (sometimes several) product from all the sellers, while users can choose the best option for themselves (shipping costs, price, seller reputation). IMO this is for a genuine benefit of the visitors.

The question is:
**Should I place nofollow tag on those links**, or let Google see what's "behind" them? 
Which option will narrow down Google's search better?

I want my site to show for Google querries where it really gives the info people are seeking, and I'd rather it NOT show when the info is not relevant to the querry. Not selling anything and the site is a non-profit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in [Google Link Schemes Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en) when you should use a nofollow tag in your site. Check this point, it's not the same but it's close:

> Buying or selling links that pass PageRank. This includes exchanging
>   money for links, or posts that contain links; exchanging goods or
>   services for links; or sending someone a “free” product in exchange
>   for them writing about it and including a link

In my opinion, it's an affiliate link (you will receive money if the visitor purchases a product) so I'll use a nofollow tag. With Google it's better to be cautious.